# gitlab CI pipeline for .net

Tags: .net, gitlab

I'm entirely new to git-lab and .net, while implementing CI pipeline like the one below, encountered errors on Nuget packages

```
  -- TEST API
         -- Controllers
         -- Repository 
         -- Models
         -- Test.csproj
   -- readme.md
   --  test.sln
```

My .yml file consist of following lines

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1


stages:
    - build
    
before_script:
   - "dotnet restore"


build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - "dotnet build"
```

The above execution fails by saying unable to connect to Nuget repo.

```
error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Comment: As you said, you are a begineer in this field, I would like you to check the basic first like setup, installation and also Runners in Gitlab. If, I'm not wrong runners might be missed in the setup.